# TimeStamps for DateTime and Time siche Epoch Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

How to create timestamps in dart? I have found many solution but non of them works. I need to put in get-request the timestamps. Server takes timestamps in time siche epoch format. I was trying this:

```
_asyncMethod() async {
    var url =
        "https://link/cameras/snapshot/$formatDate"; // <-- 1
    var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url), headers: {
      'cookie': cookies,
      'login': userName,
      'password': password,
      'key': apiKey
    });
    print(response.body);
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var firstPath = documentDirectory.path + "/image";
    var filePathAndName = documentDirectory.path + 'image/png';
    await Directory(firstPath).create(recursive: true);
    File file2 = File(filePathAndName);
    file2.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);
    setState(() {
      imageData = filePathAndName;
      dataLoaded = true;
    });
  }

  String imageData;
  bool dataLoaded = false;


   String formatDate(int milliseconds) {
     final template = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
     return template.format(DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(milliseconds));
   }
```

but the answer from the server is

```
 {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|3fc1bda-4c3086a677e6762a.","er
rors":{"timestamp":["The value 'Closure: (int) => String from Function 'formatDate':.' is not valid."]}}
```

I understand that the data is not correct but I can't understand how to solve it, because it seems like code for timestamps is correct

Comment: "Server takes timestamps in time siche epoch format" is that in seconds, milliseconds or something else?

Comment: @julemand101 in the format hours, minutes, and seconds and also month year date . I also saw the solution in this site - https://flutteragency.com/convert-timestamp-in-flutter/  but it also dosen't work

Comment: Ehh so the server does not in fact not take the data in epoch format but just a normal data format? Please show us how you want the `DateTime` to be formatted since your comment does not match your code which have: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: @julemand101 so, the main concept is that the user can download a picture from a certain period of time from a live video. I made two functions where one is a date selection, the second is a time selection. And I got this error {"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|3fbe79c-4c3086a677e6762a.","errors":{"timestamp":["The value '2022-01-25 08:02:34.163108TimeOfDay(00:00)' is not valid."]}}  so it still isn't correct time and data and api devs says it should be sicne epoch time

Comment: Yes. When somebody are asking for epoch time, they want it in seconds,. milliseconds or microseconds since epoch. This is the reason for my first question. But glad it works now ;)

Comment: @julemand101 oh, can I ask another stupid question: Can I make it so that the user can select the date and time himself on the datepicker?

Comment: I don't know anything about Flutter so I am not the right guy to ask that question. :)